# How to show popup in obout:grid using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to show one `popup` using `obout:grid` in `asp.net`

Like alert box *if customer want continue click `yes` it has to continue* or *click `cancel` it is same page only*.

Please help me, very thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, would you please share it and tell us what doesn't work?

Comment: I think what you want to implement is something called "Dirty Page", here is a sample blog which can guide you to do it http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2008/03/dirty-checking-in-aspnet-revisited.html

Comment: There are multiple methods based on what you want to achieve. You can show popup from asp.net (requires postback) or from javascript directly. You can also redirect to a custom form for same dialog. So, question is exactly when and how you want to show the alert. And obviously an idea of what you have tried till now. Note that this is not a place to ask people to do your work for you. Come back when you have tried something and it failed.